# How do I add together two arrays and get the result back as one number? Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to add together two arrays of numbers and print the result as a total number.

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [4, 5, 6]
arr1 + arr2
```

Just gives me = 1 2 3 4 5 6, but I want 21.

Comment: _"I need to add together two arrays of numbers"_ – you want to add the numbers from both arrays, not the arrays themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by "add together two arrays"? How did you arrive at the result `21`? It makes no sense to me. I can see two different ways to interpret the sentence "add together two arrays": concatenation or piecewise addition. The result of concatenation would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. The result of piecewise addition would be `[5, 7, 9]`. I don't see how `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]` would lead to `21`. Can you explain what the rules are to construct your desired result? It is very hard to derive a general set of rules from only a single example, especially if the example is not explained.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) method

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [4, 5, 6]

(arr1 + arr2).sum
```

Comment: Or without the intermediate array: `arr1.sum + arr2.sum`

Comment: Also, this happens to work: `arr1.chain(arr2).sum`

Answer (score 1):

This is another way

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [4, 5, 6]

p (arr1 + arr2).reduce(:+)
```

Output

```
21
```

Comment: Ruby 2.4.6 introduced `Array#sum`. Also, because you're using `p` method, the returned result is `nil`.

Comment: I executed the above code and it's printing 21 without having any problem.

Comment: Outputting 21 is a side-effect. The result is `nil`. (Sorry for being picky.)

Comment: @user3574603 `puts` returns `nil`, whereas `p` returns its argument(s)

Comment: @user3574603: Feel free to test `p 21` in irb before claiming that it returns `nil`, twice.